# Faster way to get a directory listing than invoking "ls" in a subprocess

Tags: python, performance, directory-listing

After a search, and some test runs both os.popen()+read() and subprocess.check_output() seem to be almost equivalent for reading out the contents of a folder. Is there a way to improve either a combination of os.popen()+read() or subprocess.check_output()? I have to `ls` a number of folders and read the outputs, and using either of the above is similar, but represents the major bottleneck according to profiling results.

Comment: I've corrected the title of your question to be more obviously what I understand it to be.  Your original title did not indicate what you were using a subprocess for, which may have discouraged people from answering.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) and/or [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), and perhaps also the [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) family of functions.  These are (Python bindings to) the same primitives that `ls` uses itself, so anything you can do by parsing the output of `ls` you can do with these.  I recommend you read carefully through everything the [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html), [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html), and [stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) modules offer; there may be other things you don't need an external program to do.

You should probably also read the documentation for [`stat`, the underlying system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) -- it's C-oriented, but it'll help you understand what `os.stat` does.

Comment: Oh yeah, os.listdir is exactly what I need! Will thoroughly read about os module now...For some reason I only checked the subprocess documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just read the directory contents directly with [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir)?  Why do you need to shell out to `ls`?  If you need more information about files in addition to just the filenames, you can also use [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat).  It's much more efficient to do the system calls yourself than to create subprocesses to do it for you.

For doing entirely directory traversals, there's [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk).  The [`shutil` module](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) also has some useful functions.

Comment: The `glob` module also offers a useful shortcut, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use glob:

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> glob('*')
```

The syntax is the same.

e.g.

```
glob('*.txt')  # the same as "ls *.txt"
```